# Is there a solution to $(f\circ g)'(x)=(f'\circ g')(x)$?

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

So the chain rule is defined as
$$
 \frac{df(g(x))}{dx}=\frac{df}{dg}\frac{dg}{dx}
$$
Is there a function where the derivative of a function composition is the composition of the derivatives, essentially solving this DE:
$$
 \frac{df}{dg}\frac{dg}{dx}=\frac{df(\frac{dg}{dx})}{dx}=(f'\circ g')(x)=f'(g'(x))
$$

Comment: We want $f'(g(x)) g'(x) = f' (g'(x))$. Take $g(x) = x$. Then we need $f'(x) = f'(1)$, to which $f(x) = f'(1)x + C$ is a solution for any $C \in \mathbb{R}$.